# Управление формами . php/html

Tags: php, html, форма

Имеем несколько последовательных форм с инпут/техт.
Вводим цифры - нажимаем кнопку - формы выходят в порядке убывания введенных значений. Возможно ли сделать все формы в одной? Что посоветуете? Блоками?

Comment: Код формы лучше выложи, вопрос не понятен.

Comment: если несколько форм на странице, то после нажатия на кнопку (видимо submit) на сервер отправится только одна форма, вы понятия элемент формы с самой формой не путаете?